# postgresql 3 error: Can't connect the application to database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

My error is:

```
May 08, 2014 3:03:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Licenta] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at proiect.GetCarte.GetCarte2(GetCarte.java:23)
    at org.apache.jsp.Carti_jsp._jspService(Carti_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code.

```
import beans.Carte;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class GetCarte {

    public ArrayList<Carte> GetCarte2 () throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
     {
        ArrayList<Carte> carti = new ArrayList<Carte>();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



       // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Class.forName(" postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/inventarbiblioteca", "root", "password");
        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        Carte carte=new Carte();

        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from carte");

        while (rs.next()) {
            int identificatorCarte=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("identificatorCarte"));
              int ISBN=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ISBN"));
                    String titlul=rs.getString("titlul");
                    String autori=rs.getString("autori");
                    String editura=rs.getString("editura");
                    int anAparitie=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("anAparitie"));
                    int editie=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("editie"));
                    int pret=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("pret"));
                    int idDomeniu=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("idDomeniu"));
                    String observatiiCarte=rs.getString("observatiiCarte");
                    carte = new Carte (identificatorCarte, ISBN, titlul, autori, editura, anAparitie, editie, pret, idDomeniu, observatiiCarte );
                    System.out.println("adauga carte " + carte.getTitlul());
                    carti.add(carte);

        } 

       System.out.println("Titluri:");
    for(Carte t : carti) 
    {
        System.out.println(t.getTitlul());
    }

        return carti;
}


    public ArrayList<Carte> GetSearchedCarte (String searched) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
     {
        ArrayList<Carte> carti = new ArrayList<Carte>();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proiect", "root", "root");
        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        Carte carte=new Carte();

        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from carte where titlul like '%" + searched + "%'");

        while (rs.next()) {
            int identificatorCarte=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("identificatorCarte"));
              int ISBN=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ISBN"));
                    String titlul=rs.getString("titlul");
                    String autori=rs.getString("autori");
                    String editura=rs.getString("editura");
                    int anAparitie=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("anAparitie"));
                    int editie=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("editie"));
                    int pret=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("pret"));
                    int idDomeniu=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("idDomeniu"));
                    String observatiiCarte=rs.getString("observatiiCarte");
                    carte = new Carte (identificatorCarte, ISBN, titlul, autori, editura, anAparitie, editie, pret, idDomeniu, observatiiCarte );
                    System.out.println("adauga carte " + carte.getTitlul());
                    carti.add(carte);

        } 

        System.out.println("Titluri:");
    for(Carte t : carti) 
    {
        System.out.println(t.getTitlul());
    }

        return carti;
}

    public Carte GetCarteByISBN (int isbn) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
     {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Carte t = new Carte();



        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proiect", "root", "root");
        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        Carte carte = new Carte();

        rs = st.executeQuery("select * from carte where identificatorCarte=" + isbn);

        if (rs.next()) {
            int identificatorCarte=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("identificatorCarte"));
              int ISBN=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ISBN"));
                    String titlul=rs.getString("titlul");
                    String autori=rs.getString("autori");
                    String editura=rs.getString("editura");
                    int anAparitie=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("anAparitie"));
                    int editie=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("editie"));
                    int pret=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("pret"));
                    int idDomeniu=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("idDomeniu"));
                    String observatiiCarte=rs.getString("observatiiCarte");
                    carte = new Carte (identificatorCarte, ISBN, titlul, autori, editura, anAparitie, editie, pret, idDomeniu, observatiiCarte );
                    System.out.println("adauga carte " + carte.getTitlul());



        }

        return carte;
}
}
```

Comment: SO is not a debugging service

Comment: Drivers are not loaded. Download jdbc driver for postgresql and put it in class path. This is the link http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: How on earth could a question like this get an upvote..

Comment: Off-topic. Possibly on-topic on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should add `JDBC` `PostgreSQL` Driver to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong name of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

The error is here:

```
    Class.forName(" postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3");
```

`postgressql-9.3.1101.jdbc3` is the name of the JAR, not the name of the class.  You need to load the class instead:

```
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

See also http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/load.html.